ECharts Connected Local JSON Data
I'm using a simple donut (pie) EChart in an HMI application. The purpose is to display a loading wheel graphic which can be linked to live data. I need help figuring out how to link the chart to local dynamic JSON data so that the chart updates in real time without requiring a reload in the browser.
Loader Wheel
This is being done in HMI software for an offline application, using an HMTL page with some JavaScript to render it in an embedded web browser. The data is a simple array of two values, the first of which is the % (of max 100) and the other is the complement so that the darker color of the donut always represents % of total circumference.
I've managed to configure the script so that data values are pulled from a JSON source file in the local directory. The HMI software has a C# API, so at runtime I can update the values in that JSON file, which is the dynamic part.
My biggest handicap at the moment is that I don't know JavaScript. I'm cobbling this together based on a ton of online research and learning as I go.
var dom = document.getElementById('container');
        var myChart = echarts.init(dom, null, {
            renderer: 'svg',
            useDirtyRect: false
        });
        var app = {};

        $.get('data.json').done(function(data) {
          myChart.setOption({
            toolbox: {
              feature: {
                saveAsImage: {
                  name: "loader.svg",
                  type: "svg"
                }
              }
            },
            series: [
              {
                name: 'Loader',
                type: 'pie',
                radius: ['85%', '100%'],
                avoidLabelOverlap: false,
                label: {
                  show: false,
                  position: 'center'
                },
                emphasis: {
                  disabled: true
                },
                percentPrecision: 1,
                labelLine: {
                  show: false
                },
                data: data.values,
                color: ['#4b4b4b', '#ffffff'],
                emptyCircleStyle: {
                  color: "rgb(255, 0, 0)"
                },
                itemStyle: {
                  borderColor: '#737373',
                  borderWidth: 0.5,
                  borderType: "solid"
                },
                animation: false,
                showEmptyCircle: true
              }
          ],
          backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5'
          })
        });

        setInterval(function () {
          $.get('data.json');
          myChart.setOption({
            series: [{
                data: data.values
            }]
          });
        }, 500);

        window.addEventListener('resize', myChart.resize);

The setInterval function is something I just added which does not seem to work. I'm not sure why.
Here is the HTML:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" style="height: 100%">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
<body style="height: 100%; margin: 0">
  <div id="container" style="height: 100%"></div>

  <script src="./jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./echarts.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./Loader-Template.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

Ideally, it would be nice to have the whole thing spit out as an SVG where I can bind a dynamic value and it would update the path live and display accordingly. I'm guessing this is beyond the limitations though. Anyways, I feel like I'm close enough with the JS solution, I just need help getting over the finish line.

The isolated $.get('data.json'); doesn't update your data; you have to use in the function of setInterval the same pattern you have used to pull the data initially: $.get('data.json').done(function(data) { myChart.setOption({ .....
